# Vk Api: Error 901

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Недавно, при написании бота для сообщества Вконтакте столкнулся с проблемой при добавлении клавиатуры. Дело в том, что вылазит ошибка: 901: нет разрешения на отправку сообщений. Для теста сообщения я отправлял себе. Все разрешения есть и в группу я сам писал. Вот сижу ломаю голову, в документации и в гугле не нашёл нормальных ответов. Надеюсь на помощь! Спасибо.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import vk_api
import random2
from config import config_pass
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor

token = config_pass

bh = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
give = bh.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(bh)

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

vk = vk_session.get_api()

keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)

def blasthack(id, text):
    bh.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id': 0})

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
   if event.to_me:

      message = event.text.lower()
      id = event.user_id

      if message == 'начать':
        blasthack(id, 'тут мой текст он никому не нужен')

      elif message == 'команды':
        blasthack(id, 'тут тоже')

      elif message == 'инфо':
        blasthack(id, 'и тутт')

      elif message == 'заказать':
        blasthack(id, 'и тут')
      elif message == 'услуги':
        blasthack(id, 'и тут')
      elif message == 'товары':
        blasthack(id, 'тут естественно тоже')

        keyboard.add_button('Белая кнопка', color=VkKeyboardColor.SECONDARY)
        keyboard.add_button('Зелёная кнопка', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)

        keyboard.add_line()  # Переход на вторую строку
        keyboard.add_button('Красная кнопка', color=VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)

        keyboard.add_line()
        keyboard.add_button('Синяя кнопка', color=VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)

        vk.messages.send(
              peer_id=410050173,
              message='Пример клавиатуры',
              keyboard=keyboard.get_keyboard(),
              random_id=0
        )   

      else:
        messages = ['и тут', 'тут', 'не тут']
        msg_fail = random2.choice(messages)
        blasthack(id, msg_fail )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Причина была в том, что в блоке кода, который отаечает за отправление клавиатуры, был указан старый `peer_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать своему сообществу сначала, а потом пытаться написать от сообщества себе

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/658150)

Comment: @Spatz
Ровно этот набор действий решил аналогичную проблему для меня, почему здесь не содержится решения?

Comment: К сожалению не помогло.